# Pinterest-style image presentation page?

Tags: 7, views, media

Any Ideas how to create pinterest style image presentation page(view)?

Basically, it is like a page that have images in columns, images in each column have same width but different height.

Comment: I restored the question to the original one. I think the question could use some work however. Given how the question is phrased, I don't think neither my (now deleted) answer, or the edit was incorrect.

Comment: Please see [this meta discussion](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/763/is-how-do-i-copy-part-of-site-x-an-appropriate-type-of-question), to understand why I did the edits that I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that, you need to use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) jQuery plugin. With Drupal you've [this module](http://drupal.org/project/views_fluidgrid) but it's not available yet for Drupal 7.x, so you should either make your own template with the plugin or try to port the mentioned module into Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small module for making pinterest-style galleries with Drupal. It's in a sandbox at the moment here:
http://drupal.org/sandbox/MarkConroy/1903438

You can see a demonstration of it here: [www.adesignforlife.net/pinterest-galleries](http://www.adesignforlife.net/pinterest-galleries) - click on any gallery to see the images also in a Pinterest style.

It basically uses the masonry js library and adds some CSS to the images.